# Proper CSS Code For Id Selector Not Type Or Class For A Certain Event

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two spans.  Each span has an id tag.  I don't want the spans to have a class tag.  I want to use css to underline the text in the span when the mouse hovers over it.  What is the proper code to do this on a single line in my css file?

```
<span id=spanImagePreview1>Text Here <img src=url></span>
<span id=spanImagePreview2>Text Here <img src=url></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a selector that matches both elements:

```
#spanImagePreview1:hover, #spanImagePreview2:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9RxEb/

Comment: Thanks, but that exact code doesn't seem to work.  I'm still a bit fuzzy on the best/exact syntax of doing this a single line.

Comment: @the_maxx keep your `id`'s in quotes like `id="spanImagePreview1"` in your HTML code. It will work.

Comment: @Mr_Green: That is not necessary. It is just a typo in the answer.

Comment: Just two typos. A missing `#` and `_` instead of `:`.

Comment: Everyday I am learning new things here. thank you @BoltClock :)

Comment: Quotation mark are requires around attribute values in XHTML, but not in HTML (unless there are spaces in the value).

Answer (score 1):

mutliple options:

if you have only these two spans: `span:hover {text-decoration:underline;}`

if they are descendants of a specific element `#element span:hover {text-decoration:underline;}`

if the spans you have have a pattern for their id try `span[id*="spanImagePreview"] {text-decoration:underline;}`

Comment: Thank you.  I do have multiple spans that do different things.  I didn't know about the pattern matching possibility!